# Accumulating cell values in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Suppose I have a workbook that uses `Rand()` in some of its cells, and eventually yields some result in `A1`.

How can I create a record of say 100 or 500 values that appear in that cell (following refreshes)?

I am guessing it is possible to do some VBA lookup and log the results, but I was wondering if there is some built-in way to do this (maybe using scenarios or goal seeking or something similar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First include a new tab called **hystory**  to hold the results.  Then insert the following event macro in the worksheet code area of your original worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Dim hys As Worksheet, N As Long
    Set hys = Sheets("hystory")
    N = hys.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    N = wf.Min(N, Rows.Count)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        hys.Cells(N, "A").Value = [A1]
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as **.xlsm** rather than **.xlsx**

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work**!

Comment: Thanks,
for my needs I would probably use a loop that forces calculations and then copies the cell as I don'w want it to run forever on one hand and I also don't want to force the refreshes manually... The maing point of the Q was that `I was wondering if there is some built-in way to do this` but I am guessing the answer for this is a NO...

Comment: The answer is............**YES!!**......we can implement a loop......pick a cell to contain the iteration count.....

Answer (score 0):

A conventional way to do this is to **Copy** the random values and then **Paste Values**. 
You could record this as a macro if you want.

Comment: But, assuming I understood correctly, then the OP would have to manually copy `A1` each time he recalculated the worksheet. Your solution is good if getting a series of random values all lined up.

Comment: Hmm, I may have misread the question. I interpreted it to mean that the OP was talking about cells `A1` through `A100`. But you believe that he’s talking about 100 refreshes of one cell? Still, as I suggested, my answer could be recorded as a macro. The trick would be to get it to save values in `B1` through `B100` rather than `B1`, 100 times.